# Possible bug with GCC, foreach loops operate on shadows, rather than the actual objects

Tags: c++, gcc

I believe I've stumbled upon a bug in GCC 4.82

consider the following MCVE:

```
class foreachtestobject
{
    std::string somevalue;

public:
    foreachtestobject(int i)
    {
        somevalue = "default value "+to_string(i);
    }

    void reSetSomeValue(string newvalue)
    {
        somevalue = newvalue;
    }

    string getValue()
    {
        return somevalue;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<foreachtestobject> vec;
    vec.push_back(foreachtestobject(1));
    vec.push_back(foreachtestobject(2));

    //reading via foreach is unproblematic
    for(auto obj : vec )
    {
        cout<<"Object is: "<<obj.getValue()<<endl;
    }

    //changing values inside a foreach
    for (auto obj : vec)
    {
        obj.reSetSomeValue("new name");
    }

    //printing a second time
    for(auto obj : vec )
    {
        cout<<"Object is: "<<obj.getValue()<<endl;
    }//Notice that nothing has changed.

    //now changing via conventional loop
    for (int i = 0; i<vec.size();i++)
    {
        vec[i].reSetSomeValue("this worked");
    }

    //Printing a third time
    for(auto obj : vec )
    {
        cout<<"Object is: "<<obj.getValue()<<endl;
    }//Notice how the values have been changed correctly.
}
```

Running the code through QTs debugger, it appears that the foreach loops create temporary copies of the objects, the memory addresses do not match either of the two actual objects. So when reSetSomeValue is called, the function on the shadow objects are called instead.

I might add that I am not entirely sure QT actually compiles with gcc 4.8.2. I happen to know that I updated GCC some time ago, I don't know if QT automatically takes to use the updated version. the command GCC --version reports 4.8.2.

This strikes me as down right odd, not to mention inefficient, if each object iterated over is copied, it represent a considerable overhead. According to any sources I find, foreach loops should work in the same manner as conventional for loops, yet here it does not.

When that's said, is this a bug? If not, why?

Comment: You _do_ request a copy with `for ( auto obj : vec )`. If you want a reference, you need to request a reference: `for ( auto& obj : vec )`.

Comment: Because your using `auto` instead of `auto&` or `const auto&` or `auto&&`.

Comment: Just FYI, This is not an MCVE. I can copy an MCVE, paste to ideone.com (or my local editor), hit "Run" and get the same results you have.

Comment: @n.m.: Not to mention the annoyance of missing headers and `using`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(auto obj : vec )
```

does and should create copies of the elements of the range, that's in the language rules. If you want a reference, say so:

```
for(auto &obj : vec )
```

Answer (score 2):

> it appears that the foreach loops create temporary copies of the objects

Did it not occur to you that this is because *that's the code you wrote*? The only "bug" here is with you: you're operating on copies of your array elements.

If you wish to operate on the original versions, use [*references*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)). For example:

```
for (auto& el : container)
//       ^
```

When you have a problem, accusing the compiler of being buggy is the last resort, not the first (unless you're using Visual Studio). At least look up what the ranged-for loop construct means and does.

Comment: I am starting to believe that `auto` introduces a lot of trouble because it delivers less than people think it does. Programmers attribute magic powers to it, along the lines of "make a reference if it's better, else a copy".

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Agreed, except for the "starting to" part :) I've been saying this from the start.

Comment: Just out of interest, how much irony is in your statement about Visual Studio? And are you specifically talking about the IDE or about Visual C++ (i.e. the compiler) itself? I'm somewhat worried that beginners may take that sentence literally.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: 50%. And 50%